# BMP Image Processing in Intel Mac

Tags: macos, applescript, sips

I was using 'sips' in powerpc machine to process the bmp images. But the same sips in imac is not processing the images which powerpc mac can. It just simply tells that the image is not valid. But it opens fine in windows, linux and power pc mac.
Here is the Scenario : 
I use bmp images in my mac apple script installer. The bmp images are supplied by my customers. The issue i face is, when i compile the applescript installer with the customer provided images, i get an shrinked image in the installer. But when the images are saved in powerpc mac and compiled,it worked fine.

So i used sips just to save the images in powerpc. But intel mac machines are not accepting the images.

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this problem ..?
I would need to get sips work or other terminal based program to process the images in intel mac machine.
Please someone shed light on this one.

Comment: can you edit your question to add how you are calling sips on the command line (in other words, when you are testing, before you embed your command into AppleScript)?  I did find [this tutorial](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/07/convert-images-using-terminal.html) regarding sips and how to convert from png to bmp.

Comment: @Manikanda raj S: "BMP" in itself doesn't mean that much: there are a *lot* of different BMP format.  You can have compressed BMP, uncompressed, you can even wrap PNG inside BMP etc.  As a result it is frequent with BMP tools to have one tool generating a BMP that another one cannot open (I recently got a message like: *"BMP format is too recent, we do not support it yet"*).  Would it be possible for you to consider another format, which may work on both machines?  If you want lossless, I'd suggest you give PNG a try.

Comment: Hi Michael, the command i m using is "sips -s format bmp wizardsmall.bmp --out wizardsmall.bmp" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify exactly what you were doing to the images, but [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is always an excellent choice for command-line image processing.

Comment: Hi, I just want to save the files in command line.Once i save the files in Mac, i can use that with no problems in Mac AppleScript installer. I have been to ImageMagick too, but sips had been useful to me in powerpc mac. Wonder why its not working in IMac for the same images.  sips in imac says the image is not valid while the power pc processes it good.